# Remove a metric from Datadog

Tags: datadog

I'd like to remove a custom metric that I've created with my Datadog account. Is there a way to do that ?

I've checked the docs, and did not find anything relevant for the metrics deletion.

Regards,
Blured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just stop sending it. After an hour or so it will stop appearing in all the autofill dropdowns.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't any way to delete the metrics yet. The only option is to stop sending it and after 2 weeks, it wont showup on the metrics dropdown. However metric is still available for upto 1.5 years.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop sending log metrics by deleting them here:
https://app.datadoghq.com/logs/pipelines/generate-metrics

It will continue to be available in Metrics Summary / Explorer as others have already mentioned, but this will stop sending them.